# Using RS flip-flops to solve this problem

Tags: flipflop

Consider a rail with a wheel mounted on it. The wheel can move from point A to B or B to A. There is a linear sensor to track the position of wheel between A and B. At point A, the linear sensor gives converted digital output 0 and at B it gives 1000. We will consider the wheel to be midway between A and B when the linear sensor gives reading as 500. Lets say this point it C.

Something like>

A___________C___________B

0__________500__________1000

Now to the electronics part:

1. Button 1 moves the wheel to A by starting motor x.
2. Button 2 moves the wheel to B by starting moor y.
3. Button 3 moves the wheel to the center point irrespective of its starting position, that is, A to C or B to C or from anywhere in between towards C.

The same motors x and y are used, based on the direction.

I have solved all 3 conditions above but there is one more that I am not able to implement. Sometimes when pressing button 3 to move point C, it can happen that the wheel may be acted upon by an external force and cross point C rather than stopping at it. In this case, we do not want that our existing logic starts moving the wheel back towards point C. Think of this like a pendulum effect with the wheel oscillating and crossing over point C before eventually coming to a stop.

So, the ideal condition is that if the wheel crosses over C while button 3 is being pressed, the motors x and y both should be shut off after the first time the wheel reaches or crosses C.

My friend suggested that I should use flip-flops to solve this but I havent managed.

Please help!!

Comment: ok, I think there are something unlogical here. If you keep pressing button 3, what you should expect the system to do is to continue trying to bring the wheel to point C.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some untested microcontroller pseudo-code to analyse. This would be simple to implement on an Arduino platform or similar. If you insist on using logic circuits it may help you work out the logic.

```
// Three buttons, left, centre and right: btnL, btnC, btnR.
// Two motors: motorX moves right, motorY moves left.
// Position: p

void loop(){
  // Left motion
  if(btnL && (p > 0) {motorX = true} else {motorX = false}

  // Right motion
  if(btnR && (p < 1000) {motorY = true} else {motorY = false}


  // Centre-cross detection
  // The variable 'centrePass' tracks whether a mid-point transition has occured.
  if(btnC && motorX && (p >= 500) {centrePass = true}
  if(btnC && motorY && (p <= 500) {centrePass = true}
  if(!btnC) centrePass = false

  // Centre motion
  if(btnC && !centrePass) {
    if(p < 500) {motorX = true} else {motorX = false}
    if(p > 500) {motorY = true} else {motorY = false}
  } else {
    motorX = false;
    motorY = false;
  }
}
```